# display page numbers in selectbox using angular 2/ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am fetching the number of pages for a resultset using API call. But i want to show the number of pages list inside selectbox using angular 2/ionic 2.

Expected output is:

1,2,3,4,5,6

```
 export class TransactionsPage {
      perPageValues:any; 

     constructor(){
       this.perPageValues= 6;
     }
    }
```

I tried in the following way but not working.

### View

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Page</ion-label>
    <ion-select [formControl]="page">
      <ion-option  *ngFor="#perPage of perPageValues" [value]="perPage">{{perPage}}</ion-option>           
     </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: perPageValues is a number you need array.

Comment: try with `this.perPageValues = [1,2,3,4,5,6];`

Comment: @sebaferrearas, It is a dynamic value

Comment: @suraj rao, I am getting the following output, "page": {
    "size": 30,
    "totalElements": 77,
    "totalPages": 3,
    "number": 2
  }

Comment: as others have  mentioned , you will have to set an array not a number.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the following way,

```
this.pageValues = Array.from(Array(data.page.totalPages),(x,i)=>i+1);
```